# What are easy sources of auram? 1.7.10 (thaumcraft 4.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I am playing direwolf 20 1.7.10 and I got to the point where I can get silverwood wand and I want to have it with thaumium wand caps because why not but I need auram to activate the wand caps and you get auram from beacons and nether stars just really end game stuff. Is there a way to get auram without killing withers or stuff like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Get a reusable safari net and capture a wisp and put the safari net in the auto-spawner, there you can kill wisps and you have a chance of getting auram, or find an aura node that contains auram and break it.

Answer (score 2):

Auram already comes from Ethereal Esscence, which you can get from breaking a node. All types of Ethereal Esscence contain it.

Answer (score -1):

Euclidaisy, in the Apocrypha tab in the Thaumonnomicon, produces a ton of auram at a relatively low cost.